# VueJs highstock cant draw graph properly

Tags: javascript, laravel, vue.js, highcharts

This is my VueJS code, i use this lib https://www.npmjs.com/package/highcharts-vue
So i dont know how i can get data and set it to series before the graph is drawn. Or if this is not posible, how can i redraw graph properly? Becouse now i set some default data, then get data from page, and redraw graph, but when its done and i see my graph, the scrollbar go to the left side and has a very small range. So how set options without change scrollbar and range selector?

```
<template>
  <highcharts :constructor-type="'stockChart'" :options="options" :updateArgs="[true, false]" ref="linerchart"></highcharts>
</template>

<script>
    import {Chart} from 'highcharts-vue'
    import Highcharts from 'highcharts'
    import stockInit from 'highcharts/modules/stock'
    stockInit(Highcharts)
    export default {
      data: () => ({
        obj: [],
        names: ['CAFF'],
        options: {
          credits: { enabled: false },
          rangeSelector: {
            selected: 1,
            inputEnabled: false,
            buttonTheme: {
                visibility: 'visible'
            }
          },
          yAxis: {
            labels: {
                formatter: function () {
                    return (this.value > 0 ? ' + ' : '') + this.value + '%';
                }
            },
            plotLines: [{
                value: 0,
                width: 2,
                color: 'silver'
            }]
          },
          plotOptions: {
            series: {
              compare: 'percent',
              showCheckbox: false,
              events: {
                checkboxClick: function (event) {
                  if (event.checked) {
                      this.show();
                  } else {
                      this.hide();
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          },
          tooltip: {
            pointFormat: '<span style="color:{series.color}">{series.name}</span>: <b>{point.y}</b> USD<br/>',
            split: true
          },
          series: [{
            name: "CAFF",
            data: [1,2,3,4,5,6]
          }]
        }
      }),
      methods: {
        linerGraph() {
          var that = this;
          this.names.forEach(function(name, i){
            axios.get('/test/account/CAFF')
            .then(response => {
              console.log(response.data)
              that.obj.push({name: name, data: response.data});
            });
          });
          this.options.series = that.obj
        },
      },
      components: {
        highcharts: Chart
      },
      mounted() {
        console.log(this.$refs.linerchart)
        this.linerGraph();
      }
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use other VueJS lifecycle hook point to run `axios` request, because you are trying to download it when the component is already `mounted()`, so please try to use one of hook points before that one, e.g `created()`.
Here is the Lifecycle diagram from [Vue General Documentation](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/instance.html#Lifecycle-Diagram):

[image]

Comment: i used it, but its not helped me(i dont remember but if i set created insted moutent the result the same or i even cant use any this.variable becouse its undefined)

Comment: So it's hard to deduce what exactly you're doing wrong. Could you try to prepare the minimal example of the problem with moving scrollbar to the left side? I suspect that requested data is not adjusted to your current data or whole chart configuration. However, without taking a closer look on that, I'm not one hundred percent sure.